# Provide elements as inputs for an action

Tags: blueprism

I want to make my own Utility VBO where I can feed an element as input to an action and it will be used in it as a regular element.

An example would be a loop of "Wait until it exists " that I could insert in multiple places along a process.
[Sample action that continually waits until a window appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsCRC.jpg)

Can elements be valid inputs? The only idea I have so far is to map multiple possible attributes as dynamic and pass those as inputs.

Comment: The way you have your solution wired in your screenshot is not advisable. In this situation, if an unexpected state is reached and the element(s) you're waiting for don't appear, your automation will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: I agree. A more robust solution would have a loop counter that would throw an exception after X number of attempts. This is an additional argument why I would like to have this as its own action

Answer (score 0):

It's generally bad practice to use a method like that. It's really important to use a principle called ["Separation of concerns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) when developing robots. In a way, you should have all logic that interacts with the application hidden from the process, so that when developing the process you can free your mind from problems at the level of objects. All in all, I strongly advise against that solution.

But if you want to use it, then see how to guide below:

1. Think about the parameters that you want to pass from the process to object. Create an action in object that accepts these parameters as input.
2. Identify an object, chose the attributes that you want to use and set them as Dynamic.

[image]

3. Use that dynamic element in the "Wait" stage. in that stage there should be a "suspension point" button, in "Params" Column. If you click it then there should open a new window in which you can pass the parameters. Please see reference below:

[image: Image reference]

Comment: I find your reminder about the separation of concerns important, although not relevant to the problem. The created object action is intended to be used inside other objects, so there will be no mixing between object and process logic. Will this method be usable between different types of elements? In your example it is an HTML button, can it be more generic?

Comment: Oh, I didn't thought about that - if you intent to use it that way, then it's absolutely okay. Yes, that method works should work with any element and any attribute.